# Asp.Net httpcontext.current.request works on virtual windows server 2012 running iis7 but not on windows server 2016 iis10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am experiencing a very strange issue(strange to me) with `HttpContext.Current.Request.` I have recently deployed a Asp.Net site using Razor Syntax pages on Server 2016 iis 10. The issue I am experiencing with `HttpContext.Current.Request.` is that it is coming back null. only on iis 10. I have tested on another server running iis 7 and I have no issue at all. The data posts from page to page as expected. I do not believe this is a syntax issue because I have not rewritten anything since the move.

Comment: You are not supposed to call `HttpContext.Current.Request` in most cases, as `Page.Request` or `ControllerBase.Request` is the desired.

Comment: I will give that a shot. Thank you. Although changing this is less than favorable as that statement is almost everywhere throughout the code. What would be the reason why it runs on server 2012 and not 2016?

Comment: The underlying .NET Framework changes over Windows Server releases, which might amplify the side effect of using `HttpContext.Current`. This property is supposed to be only used in a few scenarios, while in most cases you should use the ones I pointed out.

Comment: I tried both of the solutions you gave and both gave an error regarding a string. the syntax is `if (HttpContext.Current.Request["Process"] == "Submit")` which returns false and `if (HttpContext.Current.Request["Process"].ToString() == "Submit")` which returns null.

Comment: Well, how can I not recognize that's "the solutions you gave"? Please edit your question to include more code, not merely the line, as that contains almost no information for others. Keep in mind I have no magic to see your screen, so I didn't give you any solution, but just hints on what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. The image type for the button was not passing the value to the second page. I changed the type to Submit and the data is posting as expected.